# Railsでform_for送信したパラメータがtableに記録されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsで簡単なメモ登録アプリを作成中ですが、Viewから新規作成し送信したレコードの中身がテーブルに記録されません。（空のレコードは作成されます）

Viewフォームがおかしいのか、Controllerの記述が悪いのか、分からない状況です。

ごく基本的な質問なので恐縮ですが、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。
Rails初心者です。

バージョン
Rails 4.2
Ruby 2.1
Gem 2.2

テーブル設計

```
create_table :tips do |t|
      t.string  :title
      t.text    :link
      t.text    :text
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string  :category
      t.timestamps
```

コントローラー

```
class TipsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    Tip.create(title: tip_params[:title], link: tip_params[:link], text: tip_params[:text], category: tip_params[:category], user_id: current_user.id)
  end

  private

  def tip_params
    params.permit(:title, :link, :text, :category)
  end
end
```

ビューの入力フォーム

```
<%= form_for @tip do |f| %>
<div >
<%= f.label :title, "TIPタイトル" %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
</div>

<div >
<%= f.label :link, "関連するリンクのアドレス" %>
<%= f.text_field :link %>
</div>

<div >
<%= f.label :text, "内容を記入しましょう" %>
<%= f.text_field :text %>
</div>

<div >
<%= f.label :category, "ジャンルを入力" %>
<%= f.text_field :category %>
</div>

<div >
<%= f.submit "投稿して共有する" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

その View から POST された場合、`params` は以下のような構造になっているはずです。(ログ中の `Started POST "/tips" for ...` の直後に `Parameters: { ... }` として表示されています。)

```
{"tip" => {"title" => "...", "link" => "...", "text" => "...", "category" => "test"}, ...}
```

このため、`tip_params` は以下のように定義する必要があります。

```
def tip_params
  params.require(:tip).permit(:title, :link, :text, :category)
end
```

まずは Rails の機能でひな形を作成して、それを修正していくのが良いでしょう。

```
(例)
rails g scaffold Tip title:string link:text text:text user_id:integer category:string
```